# Animate scrollTop after user finished scrolling body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having trouble getting `scrollTop` working on the `body` when the following CSS is set:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
html { overflow: hidden; }
body { overflow: auto; }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for the page to always scroll to a grid of 150px. So for example if the user scrolls 161px down the page, after they finish scrolling, the page will automatically scroll back to 150px.

Here's my code so far:

```
//timer
var timer = null;

//body scroll
$('body').scroll(function(){

  //clear timer
  if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);

  //set timer
  timer = setTimeout(function() {

    //scroll calculations
    var sectionOffset = $('body').scrollTop(),
        scrollAmount = Math.round(sectionOffset/150) * 150,
        scrollPx = scrollAmount + 'px';

    //lock to grid
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:scrollPx},200,'linear');
  },300);

});
```

And a fiddle showing it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/swjabxqq/1/

I've tested the code in other CSS situations and it does work. How can I scroll the body with JS/jQuery when the CSS is set as above?

Answer (score 2):

Remove this CSS:

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
body { overflow: auto; }
```

And change

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
```

To:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/swjabxqq/2/)

Comment: I can't remove the CSS, it is a required part of the design. It stops browsers like Chrome doing the scroll bounce effect. As I said in the question, I've tested the code in other CSS situations already. I need a solutions for the CSS in the question though.

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/ `The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.`

Comment: The problem you have is that setting `overflow:hidden` in your CSS is preventing scrollTop from reporting a value other than zero, I'm not sure if there is a workaround

Comment: But the element being scrolled is the body which has a value of `overflow:auto`...